# ASP.Net Core MVC: Dependency Injection by Base Type

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Before moving to ASP.Net Core, I used `Ninject` and it allowed me to inject my entity framework database context in a generic way. For example:

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<MyActualDbContext>();
```

In ASP.Net Core MVC, when using the `AddDbContext`, if I do the following, it results in the service being unresolved.

```
AddDbContext<MyActualDbContext>(x=> x.UseSqlServer("..."));
---
public class TestController: Controller {
    public DbContext Db {get; private set;}
    public TestController(DbContext Db){
        this.Db = Db;
    }
}
```

I know that I can solve this problem through using either `AddSingleton` or `AddScoped`, however, since `AddDbContext` has been specially developed to be used for handling EF data context, I'd like to know if there's any way to achieve this using that method.

If `AddDbContext` does not support this behavior, which of the alternative methods are better `AddSingletone` or `AddScoped`? I know that `AddScoped` instantiates the service once per request, but I wanna know if Singleton would result in any potential problems or not. I wanna make sure that using these two methods would not have any possible disadvantages in case of ED DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
// Or use AddTransient, makes no difference as it only wraps around the
// container resolve method
services.AddScoped<DbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyActualDbContext>());
```

but honestly I don't see a benefit in doing so, because the base class won't have any of it's DbSets so you can't use it without casting it to the original code, but this on side kind of beats the idea of having IoC at all.

And yes, singleton DbContext is problematic. It can lead to memory leaks (the tracking cache will keep growing) and if you dispose it somewhere, the DI system will always return the disposed instance of the singleton context.

Comment: DbContext has methods like "Set<>, Add<>, Entity<>, etc". allows you to use your db in a generic way. Assume you have different contexts for the same db.

Comment: `AddTransient` is not a good idea (due to the tracking mechanism of EF).

Comment: Well in this case it doesn't matter, because the lifetime of the object is controlled via `AddDbContext`. When you register it as scoped, `provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyActualDbContext>()` will always return scoped instance too, even if you call `services.AddScoped<DbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyActualDbContext>());`

Comment: And one more thing, in case of massive load(100K requests), both add transient and scoped will be less efficient than singleton since the same tracking cache has to be built again and again.

Comment: Not really. DbContext instantiation is very fast and the connections taken and put back into a connection pool by EF. But you have the positive side effect that your Tracking cache won't grow indefinitely until your application runs out of memory. Can't remember that there is a way to remove the cached entities other than creating a new context and this doesn't work well with DI, unless you abstract it away in a factory. But then you get odd behavior on when it's recreated

Comment: Do you have any idea, which one these strategies does the `AddDbContext` actually implement?

Comment: AddDbContext is Scoped by default, but you can override it with one of the method overloads. Scoped is default and recommended by the EF Core team, at least for Web applications

Comment: One more question :D, what do you think would be the advantages of using `AddDbContext` over `AddScoped` ?

Comment: With AddDbContext you can configure it (the connection string etc), with AddScoped you can't directly, you would have to register an instance of DbContextOptionsBuilder and inject this in your DbContext